# How to translate 谈情说爱 in English?

Tags: translation, idioms, verbs

The definition from Yabla (which is prettier in [Ninchanese](https://app.ninchanese.com/word/traditional/260803/%E8%B0%88%E6%83%85%E8%AF%B4%E7%88%B1) ):

- to discuss passion and talk of love (idiom); to express love with terms of endearment
- billing and cooing

And to translate the sentence:

```
你的水准能跟四爷谈情说爱。
```

The first part of the sentence without translating `谈情说爱` would be something like:

```
Based on your level, you can 谈情说爱 with fourth Lord.
```

In this context, how should `谈情说爱` be translated?

Comment: Just a side note, 四爷 in this sense is probably a just a nickname, as opposed to its literal meaning (at least, in a contemporary context).

Answer (score 2):

- 谈恋爱 = fall in love
- 谈情说爱 = romancing (what people who fell in love do)

> '[Romance](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/romancing)
>
> *a. To court, woo, or try to arouse the romantic interest of.*
>
> *b. To have a love affair with.*

```
你的水准能跟四爷谈情说爱。
base on your level(quality), you can romance the fourth lord.
```